# Get locale in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am currently adding some locales to my extension and command names and configuration descriptions already work.

Now I want to add translations for error messages and popups inside my extension using [vscode-nls](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-nls). However it seems like it doesn't automatically determine the locale of vscode and I can't find any API for this in the documentation. Is there any way for extensions to do this yet or is it only for the built-in commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out vscode has an API for this, to get the language you can use `vscode.env.language`. I guess just base everything around this because there is no actual way to get the locale except maybe on linux by using the locale environment variables. But for language using `vscode.env.language` should be the best way to get the language in case you override it through the settings file or if you want it to work on all platforms.